# dynamic hyperlink / mailto

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript

EDIT 11/20/2017: The code provided by LOVEZ works great but is there a way to 'refresh' the screen to avoid multiple "Get Link" on screen?
[image]

As a workaround until I can figure out how to refresh the page, I just added line 10 and changed line 12

[image]

---ORIGINAL POST BELOW---

I'm trying to create a dynamic mailto link based on user input when I hover over the "Get Link" it seems to generate it correctly, but the link in the email body is cut off. Below code is what I tried but it seems to refresh my SharePoint page after it generates the link.

```
<input id="myInput" type="text">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {

var myID = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
    var msgBody = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/Lists/ListName/Item/editifs.aspx?DefaultView=ManagerComments&ID="+myID+"&SOURCE=https://tenant.sharepoint.com/SitePages/SitePage.aspx";
var myLink = "mailto:?subject=Pending Approvals&body="+msgBody;



var x = document.createElement("A");
var t = document.createTextNode("Get Link");
x.setAttribute("href", myLink);
x.appendChild(t);
document.body.appendChild(x);
}
</script>
```

[image][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the code below:

```
<input id="myInput" type="text">
<button onclick="myFunction()" type="button">Try it</button>
<span id="GetLink"></span>
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction() {
    var myID = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
    var msgBody = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/Lists/ListName/Item/editifs.aspx?DefaultView=ManagerComments&ID="+myID+"&SOURCE=https://tenant.sharepoint.com/SitePages/SitePage.aspx";
    var myLink = "mailto:?subject=Pending Approvals&body="+encodeURIComponent(msgBody);
    var linkHtml="<a href='"+myLink+"'>Get Link</a>";
    document.getElementById("GetLink").innerHTML=linkHtml;
}
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: It works but is there a way to refresh the screen (please see original post for added question).  Thanks LOVEZ!!

Comment: I modify the code above, it will solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the javascript encodeURIComponent() method:

```
var msgBody = encodeURIComponent("https://tenant.sharepoint.com/Lists/ListName/Item/editifs.aspx?DefaultView=ManagerComments&ID="+myID+"&SOURCE=https://tenant.sharepoint.com/SitePages/SitePage.aspx");
```

You may also need to double-encode the value of SOURCE= as well, depending on how that parameter is being used.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid multiple Get Links on button click, use below:

Add    ***$("#GetLink a").remove();***

before this:

var myID = document.getElementById("myInput").value;